# When will the "site" field be absent from an "inbox_item"?

Tags: support, discussion, api-v2

According to the documentation on the [`inbox_item`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) type, the `site` field "may be absent". Under what circumstances will this occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the site has been shut down.

This is incredibly rare, but has happened a few times.

Comment: One last question... when the "site" is down, shouldn't the result be an error of some sort? Why is it that the site field is absent instead?

Comment: @Alex - there's an error if you're using the `/users/{id}/inbox` method because the site no longer exists, but if you're using `/inbox` there's no error because you're not querying a specific site.